# Radio station coverage areas for the UK

Tags: data, united-kingdom

In the US, the [FCC](http://transition.fcc.gov/) (Federal Communications Commission) publishes transmitter data about TV and Radio stations, including information about their respective service area boundaries.  Using the published data you can derive station details and coverage area maps, like what is linked [here](http://www.radio-locator.com/cgi-bin/finder?sr=Y&s=C&call=WHTZ&x=0&y=0) and [here](http://www.radio-locator.com/cgi-bin/pat?call=WHTZ&service=FM&status=L&hours=U).

Does anyone know of similar publicly available data for AM & FM radio stations in the UK?  Ultimately I would really like to find or generate coverage area maps that I can put into my own application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The BBC lists all their public [national](http://www.bbc.co.uk/reception/transmitters/radio/) and [local](http://www.bbc.co.uk/reception/transmitters/radio/local_radio_rhc.shtml) radio transmittors (with Ordnance Survey grid references).

```
Holme Moss      95.1    M   5.6kW   SE095041
Saddleworth     104.6   V   100W    SD987050
```

You could create a simple script that would create buffers around these points based on the transmitter ERP (equivalent radiated power).

If you wanted to take it to a more advanced level you could use a terrain map to block out areas.

Commercial radio stations licenses are granted by [Ofcom](http://www.ofcom.org.uk/). They maintain a list of [coverage maps](http://www.ofcom.org.uk/static/radiolicensing/mcamaps/MCAs.htm). These are all saved as PDFs, but you could try contacting them for digital copies. They also have more generalised maps [here](http://stakeholders.ofcom.org.uk/broadcasting/radio/coverage/).

[image: radio stations]

There is also a site with scans of [printed transmitter maps](http://www.mds975.co.uk/txmaps/txmaps.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction.  It definitely looks like the right place for me to start.